# margin problem with firefox 4

Tags: css, firefox4

I just updated to firefox 4, and it's messing up my sidebar. I have a contact form in  my sidebar. If i give 1px margin to my texarea, it aligns fine in all browsers except firefox 4. It looks fine in FF 4 if i give it a 3 px margin. How can I solve it? my css for textarea:

```
textarea {
background:  #0D1E2A;
border: 1px solid #102B3E;
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-moz-border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
padding: 1px;
margin-left:1px;
width:145px;
overflow:auto;}
```

Comment: Can you provide a live demo or a screenshot? I can't tell what **messed up** means just by looking at CSS.

Comment: do you know that youre supposed to accept answers?

Comment: hi, here's two screenshota. one's of ff4 and other the previous version. you'll the textarea is sticking just a little bit off in ff4.
ff4: http://tinypic.com/r/29b1z04/7
the previous version: http://i56.tinypic.com/wbf902.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have to do with applying border-radius to only Firefox and no others but without a link or the complete markup, it's all a wild guess. I also don't recall which browsers support box-shadow.